# How can I fix my leaning garage wall

Tags: walls, garage, foundation, sill

The gable wall in my garage is leaning. The sill plate seems to have slipped off the foundation. The sill plate is broken and the lower end of a stud is missing around where it's broken.

The foundation is not totally crumbling but I'm not sure if it's solid enough to slide the wall back on top of it.

Do I jack up the wall, push it and anchor it back to the concrete?

I can sister the broken stud. What about the sill plate?

Should I replace the whole plate, or can I just reinforce that section?

Could this damage be caused by settling, Or did someone drive their car into the wall?

[image: broken sill plate and missing stud]

[image: sill plate gap]

Comment: What's on the opposite side of that wall?

Comment: Is this in a place that could have been struck by a car?

Comment: It's the rear wall, so it could have easily been stuck but a car. Behind it is nothing, some yard space.

Comment: How much out of plumb is it? Can you get someone to hold a 4' level vertical showing the gap between the wall and plumb over that distance? In the 2nd pic, it does look like the broken stud has been sistered already, did I miss something?

Comment: It's about 3 inches out of plumb at the floor. The first picture shows the missing stud. The 2x4 in the right on the second picture is not a wall stud. It's just a remnant of some shelving that used to be there.